# Defining a custom ‘wrapfig’ environment

Tags: packages, environments, debugging, wrapfigure

[ This is an updated version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233031/latex-defining-a-custom-wrapfig-environment ]

The `wrapfig` package interacts badly with the setup and teardown done by `\begin` and `\end`.  Concretely, this is not typeset correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newenvironment{pullquote}
  {\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{2in}\large}
  {\end{wrapfigure}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pullquote}
Chicken chicken
\end{pullquote}
Chicken chicken chicken chicken,
chicken chicken chicken chicken.
Chicken chicken, chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken.
\end{document}
```

The "pull quote" is displaced downward to the end of the document (or to the next wrapfigure, if any) and I get a warning about collisions between wrapping environments in the log file.

But this *is* typeset correctly (note the dirty-trick use of the internal macros defined by `\newenvironment`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newenvironment{pullquote}
  {\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{2in}\large}
  {\end{wrapfigure}}
\begin{document}
\pullquote
Chicken chicken
\endpullquote
Chicken chicken chicken chicken,
chicken chicken chicken chicken.
Chicken chicken, chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken.
\end{document}
```

I am looking for concrete advice on how to fix this apparent bug in wrapfig, which AFAICT is unmaintained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One suggestion: shift the "dirty trick" inside the definition.  This seems to work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newenvironment{pullquote}
  {\wrapfigure{o}{2in}\large}
  {\endwrapfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{pullquote}
Chicken chicken
\end{pullquote}
Chicken chicken chicken chicken,
chicken chicken chicken chicken.
Chicken chicken, chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken
chicken chicken chicken chicken.
\end{document}
```

I noticed from the source that the `wrapfigure` environment is not itself defined using `\newenvironment` but simply a `\def\wrapfigure{\wrapfloat{figure}}` and `\let\endwrapfigure\endwrapfloat`.  I don't know if this has anything to do with the bad behaviour, though.

Comment: This is actually a standard rule of thumb: If you want to define an environment `newenv` that wraps an `oldenv`, you should use `\oldenv` and `\endoldenv` in the definition of `\newenvironment{newenv}{...}{...}`. The `\begin` and `\end` commands do some preparation to start/end the environment, which are not needed more than once.

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: That's useful to know! \*quietly goes back through all his old style files and removes lots of `\begin` and `\end`s before anyone notices\*  I did notice that (La)TeX will complain about unmatched `\begin` and `\end`s, but not if they're replaced by the requisite commands.

Comment: That works quite well, and gets me out of trying to debug the package!  Thank you.  @Juan: I didn't know that rule of thumb either; is that why the internal macros have names with no @ in them?

Comment: Well I don't know if *that* is precisely the reason, but it looks like a sensible one!