# Custom Wraptable Environment

Tags: environments, wrap

Let's say I have something like this

```
text text text

\begin{mywraptable}{r}{6cm}
my beautiful table
\end{mywraptable}

text text text
```

And now I define the following custom environment:

```
\newenvironment{mywraptable}[3]{%
\begin{wraptable}{#1}{#2}
\caption{#3}
}{%
\end{wraptable}
}
```

Why does the following not properly "wrap" with the surrounding text?

```
text text text

\begin{mywraptable}{r}{6cm}{hello}
my beautiful table
\end{mywraptable}

text text text
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this question was a duplicate of [Defining a custom wrapfig environemnt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/defining-a-custom-wrapfig-environment?rq=1) and was able to solve the issue by replacing `\begin{wraptable}` with `\wraptable` and `\end{wraptable}` with `\endwraptable`.