# Pullquote with background color and different font

Tags: color, environments, backgrounds, quotation

I have been able thanks to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1112/252672) to create a pull quote on the left side of the page. However, it’s missing a couple of parameters to make it more readable, such as the font family and the background color.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{Archivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%%%%%%%%this is for the pullquote%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{pullquote}
    {\wrapfigure{o}{2in}\large}
    {\endwrapfigure}


\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 

\author{x}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{This is some section title}
    
\lipsum[1]
\begin{pullquote}
    A quotation to be shown here.
\end{pullquote}
\lipsum[3]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I would like to add a background color to the quote and if possible change the font family. But I do not know where to place these parameters. (I guess in the `\newenvironment{pullquote}`... but where precisely is the question)

Anyone could help out with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example using

```
%%%%%%%%this is for the pullquote%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{pullquote}[1]
{\wrapfigure{o}{2in}%
    \itshape\large%
    \color{red}#1%  
    }
{\color{black}\endwrapfigure}
```

you can get

[image: a]